# How to configure custom collection name for ELMAH MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, elmah

The default collection name for storing errors that is automatically created is "Elmah". Is there any way to specify custom collection name?

The reason of it is to have 2 or more applications sharing the same Mongo database but not messing all errors inside single collection (all apps will point to "Elmah" collection).

I expect to add an additional parameter in web.config, somewhere here for example:

```
<errorLog type="Elmah.MongoErrorLog, Elmah.MongoDB.Driver2, Version=2.1.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" connecionStringName="ELMAH.MongoDB" 
maxSize="10485760" maxDocuments="10000">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution while decompiling Elmah.MongoDB.Driver2. Code uses combination of 'Elmah' string + application name setting. So the solution will be to add application name into errorLog node of Elmah MongoDB configuration in web.config that I mentioned above:

```
<errorLog type="Elmah.MongoErrorLog, Elmah.MongoDB.Driver2, Version=2.1.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" connecionStringName="ELMAH.MongoDB" 
maxSize="10485760" maxDocuments="10000" applicationName="your_custom_name">
```